# webdev error when ran without pub on windows

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I do AngularDart development on Windows 10. I'm getting strange behavior with webdev recently. I have to run webdev like this:

```
C:\Users\galankus>C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat global run webdev
A tool to develop Dart web projects.

Usage: webdev <command> [arguments]

Global options:
-h, --help    Print this usage information.

Available commands:
  build   Run builders to build a package.
  help    Display help information for webdev.
  serve   Run a local web development server and a file system watcher that re-builds on changes.

Run "webdev help <command>" for more information about a command.
```

If I try to run it directly, the below is what I get. Any ideas on how I can debug/fix this?

```
C:\Users\galankus>webdev
Crash when formatting: [Encoding] Unable to decode bytes as UTF-8.
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..271500, inclusive: 271792
#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core/runtime/libstring_patch.dart:233:55)
#1      Source.getTextLine (package:kernel/ast.dart:5772:42)
#2      getSourceLine (package:front_end/src/fasta/messages.dart:27:9)
#3      format (package:front_end/src/fasta/command_line_reporting.dart:80:27)
#4      ProcessedOptions.format (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:206:32)
#5      ProcessedOptions.report (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:215:22)
#6      CompilerContext.report (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:67:13)
#7      Loader.addMessage (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:258:20)
#8      Loader.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:207:5)
#9      LibraryBuilder.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/library_builder.dart:89:12)
#10     SourceLoader.tokenize (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:174:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     SourceLoader.buildOutline (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:192:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     Loader.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:176:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:237:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:232:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:46)
#16     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222:31)
#17     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:19)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#20     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#21     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#22     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:117:12)
#23     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:102:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:38:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     IncrementalCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:158:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:132:39)
#27     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:174:37)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#34     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
#35     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libtimer_patch.dart:21:15)
#36     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
#37     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#38     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)

Crash when compiling file:///C:/Users/galankus/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/global_packages/webdev/bin/webdev.dart.snapshot,
at character offset 264110:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..271500, inclusive: 271792
#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core/runtime/libstring_patch.dart:233:55)
#1      Source.getTextLine (package:kernel/ast.dart:5772:42)
#2      getSourceLine (package:front_end/src/fasta/messages.dart:27:9)
#3      format (package:front_end/src/fasta/command_line_reporting.dart:80:27)
#4      ProcessedOptions.format (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:206:32)
#5      ProcessedOptions.report (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:215:22)
#6      CompilerContext.report (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:67:13)
#7      Loader.addMessage (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:258:20)
#8      Loader.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:207:5)
#9      LibraryBuilder.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/library_builder.dart:89:12)
#10     SourceLoader.tokenize (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:174:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     SourceLoader.buildOutline (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:192:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     Loader.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:176:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:237:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:232:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:46)
#16     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222:31)
#17     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:19)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#20     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#21     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#22     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:117:12)
#23     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:102:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:38:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     IncrementalCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:158:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:132:39)
#27     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:174:37)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#34     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
#35     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libtimer_patch.dart:21:15)
#36     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
#37     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#38     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)


#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core/runtime/libstring_patch.dart:233:55)
#1      Source.getTextLine (package:kernel/ast.dart:5772:42)
#2      getSourceLine (package:front_end/src/fasta/messages.dart:27:9)
#3      format (package:front_end/src/fasta/command_line_reporting.dart:80:27)
#4      ProcessedOptions.format (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:206:32)
#5      ProcessedOptions.report (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:215:22)
#6      CompilerContext.report (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:67:13)
#7      Loader.addMessage (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:258:20)
#8      Loader.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:207:5)
#9      LibraryBuilder.addCompileTimeError (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/library_builder.dart:89:12)
#10     SourceLoader.tokenize (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:174:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     SourceLoader.buildOutline (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:192:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     Loader.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/loader.dart:176:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:237:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:232:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:46)
#16     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222:31)
#17     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:19)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#20     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#21     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#22     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:117:12)
#23     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:102:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:38:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     IncrementalCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:158:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dart-sdk-windows-dev/build/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:132:39)
#27     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:174:37)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#34     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
#35     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libtimer_patch.dart:21:15)
#36     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
#37     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#38     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
```

Edit: the below did not change anything, I still get the error above.

```
C:\Users\galankus>pub global activate webdev
Package webdev is currently active at version 0.2.3.
Resolving dependencies...
+ args 1.4.3
+ charcode 1.1.1
+ collection 1.14.10
+ io 0.3.2+1
+ meta 1.1.5
+ path 1.6.1
+ pub_semver 1.4.1
+ source_span 1.4.0
+ stack_trace 1.9.2
+ string_scanner 1.0.2
+ webdev 0.2.3
+ yaml 2.1.14
Precompiling executables...
Precompiled webdev:bin\webdev.
Installed executable webdev.
Activated webdev 0.2.3.
```

Comment: Does running `pub global activate webdev` fix it?

Comment: I just tried it and I still get the error. I also tried `pub cache repair`. When I type `webdev` what exactly is executed and what's the mechanism that executes it? Is there a way to troubleshoot that? I have `which` installed in cmder and `which webdev` can't find a webdev executable.

Comment: Are you using the latest Dart version? The UTF8 exception turned up several times the last weeks but should be fixed since a while already.

Comment: Yes! Upgrading to `dart-sdk 2.0.0.68-dev-0`, followed by a `pub global activate webdev` fixed it. Thank you! Please pos the answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a bug in recent Dart versions that was fixed already.

Updating Dart and the global activated `webdev` package should fix it

To update a globally activated package, just activate it again:

```
pub global activate webdev
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Command to activate WebDev

```
dart pub global activate webdev
```